# List of variable defaults for InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

I would like to list the defaults for the global variables that are innodb specific.

The problem is that the following commands doesn't list any innodb variables:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help
/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help
```

However I can see the runtime ones with:

```
mysql -e "show global variables"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SHOW COMMAND

```
mysql --table -Ae "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'"
```

## INFORMATION_SCHEMA (MySQL 5.1+)

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE variable_name LIKE 'innodb%'"
mysql -Ae"${SQLSTMT}"
```

## my.cnf Settings

```
cat /etc/my.cnf | grep innodb
```

## MySQL Documentation

- [MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html)
- [MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html)
- [MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html)
- [MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html)

As for the runtime settings and /etc/my.cnf diff, here it is

```
mysql -uroot --table -p -ANe"SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'" > InnoDBRuntime.txt
cat /etc/my.cnf | grep innodb | sed 's/=/ /g' | awk '{print $1}' > InnoDBConfigs.txt
for X in `cat InnoDBConfigs.txt`
do
    grep "${X}" InnoDBRuntime.txt
done
```

As for the runtime settings and actual defaults, it's a little different

STEP 01) Install mysql on a DevServer with no /etc/my.cnf

STEP 02) `Run mysql -uroot -hDevServerIP -p -ANe"SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'" > InnoDBDefault.txt`

STEP 03) Run `mysql -uroot -p -ANe"SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'" > InnoDBRuntime.txt`

STEP 04) Run the Diff

```
diff InnoDBDefault.txt InnoDBRuntime.txt
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I would like to list the default values using mysql or mysqld. I know they are in the documentation of the engine, but I can not use this in an automation script.

Comment: I want to see which variables are changed in the runtime compared to the defaults, a kind of diff between "show global variables" and "/usr/sbin/mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help"

Comment: Updated my answer with the diff code...

Comment: The problem is that the code does not makes the diff with the MySQL _defaults_.

Comment: It seems that there are variable that exists only at runtime and can not be set in my.cnf or from command line. Like `autocommit`.

Comment: Added another update, which requires getting MySQL installed with no my.cnf. Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I was hoping it was a command line option to list _ALL_ defaults. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You could just keep the `InnoDBDefault.txt` file, move it to each MySQL DB Server, run Step03 on that DB Server, and run the diff. Steps 1 and 2 could be just a one-time thing.